# Pop function displaying entire list

Tags: lisp

I'm trying to display one value from the list by the function is displaying the entire list instead of one value. Code below using elisp.

```
(defun element-i (L number)
  (if (not L) nil
      (if (< (length L) number) nil
          (dotimes (i number L)
            (pop L)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're returning `L` from `dotimes`, which is the remaining list after popping `number` elements from it.

If you want to get just the element, you should return the first element of `L` using `car`.

```
(defun element-i (L number)
  (cond ((null L) nil)
        ((< (length L) number) nil)
        (t (dotimes (i number (car L))
             (pop L)))))
```

I also recommend using `cond` when you have multiple conditions to test, rather than nested `if`. And use the `null` predicate when testing a list; `not` should be used for logical contexts.